# Can we make password field blurr while we take screenshot?

Tags: events, screenshot

I want to blurr password while taking screenshot due to security purpose is there any way to do it. Also i don't want to restrict the user from taking screenshot.

Can we get event before capturing screenshot so i can hide my password?
Or other way for doing this?

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This will have to be done after taking the screenshot, however, when storing passwords it is common practice only to save the hash of the password so that if the password file is stolen then the attackers will still not be able to see what the passwords were

Comment: In short i just want event before capturing screenshot so i can hide my password.